# Is there a local database compatible with javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, local, client-side

I am looking for a client side database that I can use with javascript, and maybe a .js library that helps me with the queries. Does it even exist? Or am I dreaming?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic on SO, but check out [TaffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/) anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lots of these exist. There is a cut down version of MongoDB written in JavaScript called minimongo (https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) which is used as part of the Meteor framework. There is even a powerful database API built into most modern browsers called IndexedDB (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which is useful if you don't want to depend on another library.